# What flushmate unit will fit my kohler toilets?

Tags: toilet

My Kohler toilets have tank number K-4634-AA. I think it is a discontinued model in the Cimarron family. I want to install a flushmate on one toilet to see if the bowl cleans better when flushing. I'm unable to determine what flushmate model to purchase. The flushmate site is not straightforward. One site I visited mentioned a flushmate model for all two-piece toilets, with a couple of exceptions. I need advice on this. If possible I would like to order something online today.

Comment: The page at https://www.flushmate.com/helparea/ says a flushmate cannot be added to an existing toilet, but must be made for flushmate. Too bad. I will wait for someone to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the Kohler models that a Flushmate will fit:

Kohler
Worldwide
BARRINGTON™ PRESSURE LITE®  K-3578  Two-Piece   Elongated Raised Rim    Floor Mount, Rear Outlet

Kohler
Worldwide
HIGHLINE® PRESSURE LITE®    K-3519  Two-Piece   Elongated Raised Rim    Floor Mount, Floor Outlet

Kohler
Worldwide
SAN RAPHAEL™ COMFORT HEIGHT™ PRESSURE LITE® K-3597  One-Piece   Elongated Raised Rim    Floor Mount, Floor Outlet

Kohler
Worldwide
WELLWORTH® PRESSURE LITE®